# Matriz traspuesta en java

Tags: java, matrices

**Buenas amigos!! tengo el siguiente ejercicio:
Desarrolla un método que reciba una matriz y nos devuelva su matriz traspuesta en una
matriz nueva.**

-Aquí tengo el metodo:

```
public int[][] ejercicio17 (int[][] matriz){
int[][] nueva=new int[matriz[0].length][matriz.length];

for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
        nueva[i][j]=matriz[j][i];
    }
    
}
return nueva;
}
```

-Aquí la matriz que envío:

```
int [][] nueva;
int [][] matriz={{1,2},
                 {3,4},
                 {5,6}};


nueva=ej.ejercicio17(matriz);
ej.imprimirMatriz(nueva);
```

-Por último el metodo para imprimir la matriz:

```
public void imprimirMatriz (int[][] matriz){
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            
        }
    }
```

**El problema es que me sale el siguiente error por consola y no sé que fallo puede ser. Un saludo!**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El error se genera dentro del método **ejercicio17()** cuando asignas los valores de nueva[][]:

```
    public static int[][] ejercicio17(int[][] matriz) {
    int[][] nueva = new int[matriz[0].length][matriz.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            nueva[j][i] = matriz[i][j];
         // nueva[i][j] = matriz[j][i]; // Línea errónea
        }
    }
    return nueva;
}
```

Salida:

```
    Matriz original:
    1 2 
    3 4 
    5 6 
    
    Matriz traspuesta
    1 3 5 
    2 4 6
```

Por el error que te daba (**`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`**), entiendo que haciéndolo de la otra forma algunos de los índices se estaban aplicando de forma incorrecta, yéndose fuera de rango. Haciendo el cambio, funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Gracias amigo!!